# How to Bind Two Windows Focus in OpenBox?

Tags: window, openbox, focus, minimize

So when one window get focused/active, the other one should be also or vice versa (the second window activate the first window).

**Background:** I'm a mobile apps developer, and I want the console window to be active when the Android emulator window is also active.

[image]